# Acceso por ssh desde Raspberry a Windows 10

Tags: ssh

tengo una duda de cómo poder acceder desde la Raspberry al PC por ssh. El host y la dirección ip la tengo clara, pero la contraseña me falla porque estoy usando el sistema PIN de Windows y me dice que no es esa contraseña. Alguien que me ayude?

Comment: Si usas PIN, tienes asociado el usuario de microsoft, por lo que la contraseña tendría que ser la de esa cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Me contesto a mi mismo y pongo la solución. La clave que se ha de insertar no es la clave PIN es la clave de la cuenta asociada, es decir, la clave de la cuenta de Microsoft asociada a ese usuario.

Para resolver el problemas hacer lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutar el "Administrador de equipos"
2. Ir a "Usuarios y grupos locales -> Usuarios"
3. De aquí podemos extraer el nombre del usuario. (Cuando pide la clave PIN pone el nombre del usuario de la cuenta asociada de hotmail, que no tiene porque ser el mismo).
4. Ejecuta el "Panel de Control"
5. Ingresa en "Cuentas de Usuario"
6. Pulsa de nuevo en "Cuentas de Usuario".
7. Aquí podrás ver que hay una cuenta de correo asociada al usuario, la clave a ingresar es la de esa cuenta. Si la conoces con esto será suficiente.
8. Si no la conoces, pulsa sobre "Realizar cambios en mi cuenta en Configuración"
9. Pulsa "Administrar mi cuenta de Microsoft"
10. Se abrirá un panel en tu navegador y desde aquí puedes volver a configurar una contraseña y hacer cambios en tu cuenta.